# How to return value from server to client in DataSnap projectgroup

Tags: delphi

I write datasnap application. I should know **id of last uploaded record** on server and after that upload new records from local db using cliendataset component.

I don't realise meaning of this code, what are there Parameters[0].Value, Parameters[1].Value and how it change correctly in order to return result from server:

```
FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32();
FSelectCountryCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
Result := FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetInt32;
```

if I write manually random integer value, for example

```
 result:=10;  //FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetInt32;
```

then it works correctly and returns this value in ClientFormUnit.

My final goal is **return result value(maxcountry_id) from Server** to buttonclick  procedure of ClientForm unit

Query on server:

```
select max(country_id) as maxcountry_id from country
```

**ClientForm unit:**

```
   procedure Tclient.buttonCountryClick(Sender: TObject);
    var c:integer;
    begin
     c:=Clientmodule1.ServerMethods1Client.SelectCountry;
    
     Clientmodule1.lqCountry.close;
     Clientmodule1.lqCountry.Params[0].AsInteger:= c;
     Clientmodule1.lqCountry.close;
    end;
```

**ClientClassesUnit:**

```
 function TServerMethods1Client.SelectCountry:Integer;
  begin
   if FSelectCountryCommand = nil then
    begin
     FSelectCountryCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
     FSelectCountryCommand.CommandType := 
                   TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
     FSelectCountryCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods1.SelectCountry';
     FSelectCountryCommand.Prepare;
     end;
       
  FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32();
  FSelectCountryCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
  Result := FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetInt32;
  end;
```

**ServerMethodUnit:**

```
 function TServerMethods1.SelectCountry:Integer;
    begin
     qCountry.close;
     qCountry.Open;
     Result:= qCountryMaxCountry_id.AsInteger;
    end;
```

I tried use global variable but without success: it is seen only in project area, not in project group area.

**SOLUTION**

this code works fine:

```
FSelectCountryCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
Result := FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[0].Value.GetInt32;
```

As I understand, as select query doesn't contain parameters therefore this operator:

```
FSelectCountryCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32();
```

is redundant.

Comment: Are you aware that client and server code is executed in separate processes possibly on 2 different machines? Adding a shared unit to each project won't make them magically share global variables declared in it. Those global variables are project specific only. You will need to find another way of communication between client and server app. Why don't you just return the value as a result of method `SelectCountry`?